# Prove that if $f^2(x+y)+f^2(x-y)=2f^2(x)+2f^2(y)$ then $f(x+y) \leq f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$

Tags: functions, inequality

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ be a function that:
$$f^2(x+y)+f^2(x-y)=2f^2(x)+2f^2(y) \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$
Prove that $f(x+y) \leq f(x)+f(y) \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

This problem is from [this AOPS link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2304460p18259574).

Let $x=y=0$,then $f(0)=0$. then let $x=y$,we have
$$f^2(2x)=4f^2(x)\Longrightarrow f(2x)=2f(x)$$
let $x=2y$,then we have
$$f^2(3y)+f^2(y)=2f^2(2y)+2f^2(y)=10f^2(y)\Longrightarrow f(3x)=3f(x)$$
let $x=3y$ then we have $f(4x)=4f(x)$,and use induction we have
$$f(kx)=kf(x),\forall k\in N^{+}$$ then I can't it

Comment: What you are trying to show is that a function satisfying the parallelogram identity also satisfies the triangle inequality. Note that every norm induced by a inner product satisfies the parallelogram idendity (this also works in the other direction). Maybe this helps you doing some research on the problem :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a standard result in linear algebra. Here I write a solution accessible to high school students, as the question is originally posted as a high school contest question.

You have already shown that $f(kz) = kf(z)$ for all $k \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$ and all $z \in \Bbb R$.

Let $x, y$ be any real number.
If $f(x) = f(y) = 0$, then we have $f(x + y)^2 + f(x - y)^2 = 0$ and hence $f(x + y) = 0$.
Thus in the following we assume without loss of generality that $f(y) \neq 0$.

We write $p = \frac 1 2(f(x + y)^2 - f(x)^2 - f(y)^2)$ and prove by induction on $m + n$ that $$f(mx + ny)^2 = m^2f(x)^2 + 2mnp + n^2f(y)^2\tag{*}$$ for all nonnegative integers $m, n$.

The claim is clearly true for $m + n \leq 2$. When $m + n \geq 3$, we assume without loss of generality that $m \geq 2$ and use the original functional equation with $x, y$ replaced with $(m - 1)x + ny$ and $x$ to finish the inductive step.

We have thus proved $(*)$ for all nonnegative integers $m, n$. Using the original functional equation with $x, y$ replaced with $mx, ny$, we see that $(*)$ is in fact true for all $m \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$ and all $n \in \Bbb Z$.

Applying the identity $f(kz) = kf(z)$, we have $f(x + \lambda y)^2 = f(x)^2 + 2\lambda p + \lambda^2f(y)^2$ for all rational number $\lambda$.

Thus we know that the quadratic polynomial $Q(\lambda) = f(y)^2 \lambda^2 + 2p\lambda + f(x)^2$ takes nonnegative values for all rational number $\lambda$.
This is only possible when its discriminant is not positive. Therefore we have $p^2 \leq f(x)^2f(y)^2$, or equivalently, $|p| \leq f(x)f(y)$.

Consequently, we have $f(x + y)^2 = f(x)^2 + 2p + f(y)^2 \leq (f(x) + f(y))^2$ and hence $f(x + y) \leq f(x) + f(y)$.

Comment: Do you know some example of such functions except $f=|x|$?

Comment: @C.F.G This has been addressed in the other answer. One can define many such functions by taking a $\Bbb Q$-basis of $\Bbb R$. Usually these functions will be nonmeasurable.

Answer (score 0):

For an inner product space, we can define $\|x\|=\sqrt{(x,x)}$ to be a norm, which fulfill *triangular inequallity*: $\|x+y\|\le \|x\|+\|y\|$ by Cauchy-Schwartz inequallity. We have *parallelogram identity*:
$$
\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2=2\|x\|^2+2\|y\|^2
$$
And *polarization identity* (in real space):
$$
(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(\|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2)
$$
A proposition in functional analysis is that, norm may not be induced by an inner product, but once your norm satisfies *parallelogram identity*, you can define an inner product by *polarization identity*. And this inner product will exactly induce your original norm.

So try to define an inner product by $f$, verify it is an inner product, and then use property of inner product to prove the *triangular inequallity*.

---

It takes me a lot of time to consider the following question: If the space we're working is $\mathbb{R},$ then if $f$ is a (semi-)norm, won't we directly have $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)?$$

So we shall regard $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, and $f$ will be a **semi**-norm following $\mathbb{Q}$-linearity. You will have the $\mathbb{Q}$-linearity of your $(-,-)$ by *parallelogram identity*. Prove the (**semi**) inner product satisfies Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, using $(x+\lambda y,x+\lambda y)\ge 0,$ $\lambda\in\mathbb{Q}.$ You will need to take limit of $\lambda\rightarrow \eta\in \mathbb{R}.$ However it doesn't need the continuity of $f.$ It only uses the topology in $\mathbb{R}$.

---

Above are all my thinking and backgrounds. The following is the answer to this question, which doesn't need many techniques.

You already have: $$f(0)=0, \qquad f(kx)=kf(x),\quad\forall k\in \mathbb{Q}$$

Let $(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(f(x+y)^2-f(x-y)^2).$ Then it has the following properties:

1. $(x,x)=f(x)^2\ge 0,$ and equal to zero when $x=0$;
2. $(x,y)=(y,x),$ as $f(x-y)^2=f(y-x)^2$;
3. $(x+y,z)=(x,z)+(y,z).$ This is because:
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   (x,z)+(y,z)&=\frac{1}{4}(f(x+z)^2-f(x-z)^2+f(y+z)^2-f(y-z)^2)\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}(f(\frac{x+y}{2}+z)^2+f(\frac{x-y}{2})^2-f(\frac{x+y}{2}-z)^2-f(\frac{x-y}{2})^2)\\
   &=2(\frac{x+y}{2},z)\\
   (0,z)&=\frac{1}{4}(f(z)^2-f(-z)^2)=0\\
   (x+y,z)+(0,z)&=2(\frac{x+y}{2},z)
   \end{aligned}
   $$
4. $\forall k\in \mathbb{Q},$ $(kx,y)=k(x,y).$ Denote $F(t)=(tx,y),$ then by property 3, $F(t_1+t_2)=F(t_1)+F(t_2).$ This shows that $F(t)=tF(1),$ $\forall t\in \mathbb{Q}.$

Then we verify that $(-,-)$ satisfies Cauchy-Schwartz inequality:
$$(x,y)^2\le (x,x)(y,y).$$

Use $(x+\lambda y,x+\lambda y)\ge 0,$ $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q},$
$$
(x,x)+2\lambda(x,y)+\lambda^2(y,y)\ge 0.
$$
Let $\lambda\rightarrow -\frac{(x,y)}{(y,y)},$ the inequality keeps, so
$$
(x,x)-\frac{(x,y)^2}{(y,y)}\ge 0\Rightarrow (x,y)^2\le (x,x)(y,y).
$$

Finally, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x+y)^2&=(x+y,x+y)\\
&=(x,x)+2(x,y)+(y,y)\\
&\le(x,x)+2\sqrt{(x,x)(y,y)}+(y,y)\\
&=(\sqrt{(x,x)}+\sqrt{(y,y)})^2=(f(x)+f(y))^2
\end{aligned}
$$

Triangular inequality is proved.

So the main step is to prove $\mathbb{Q}$-linearity of the inner product and Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. Retain this two step, you can find equivalent proof by only using $f,$ without defining $(-,-).$ However, I think it's pretty  concise to prove it with the help of $(-,-).$